# Where can I find the static.json for TRAFFIC_PATTERN to convert tile output after calculateroute

Tags: here-api

I am updating current processes to use the new Routing and Maps APIs scheduled for September.
Assuming a route match that requests the TRAFFIC_PATTERN layer data

```
curl --location --request POST 'https://routematching.hereapi.com/v8/calculateroute.json?routeMatch=1&mode=fastest;truck;traffic:disabled&apiKey=xxxxxx&filetype=CSV&routemode=truck&attributes=SPEED_LIMITS_FCn(*),TRAFFIC_PATTERN_FCn(*),LINK_ATTRIBUTE_FCn(*)' \
--header 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
--data-raw 'LATITUDE,LONGITUDE,TIMESTAMP,SPEED_MPH
42.47051,-83.04737,2020-07-14T10:09:48.025Z,0
```

'

The response includes the TRAFFIC_PATTERN Json like the following

```
"TRAFFIC_PATTERN_FCN": [
                                        {
                                            "FUNCTIONAL_CLASS": "5",
                                            "AVG_SPEED": "8",
                                            "TRAVEL_DIRECTION": "B",
                                            "F_WEEKDAY": "907,907,907,907,907,907,907",
                                            "T_WEEKDAY": "907,907,907,907,907,907,907",
                                            "FREE_FLOW_SPEED": "10"
                                        }
                                    ]
```

Prior to this code change I would use a lookup of static.json of the free flow PATTERN_IDs using the old URI

```
curl --location --request GET 'https://s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com/1/static.json?apiKey=xxxxxxx&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN'
```

To do the lookup for the PATTERN_ID (907)

```
{
            "PATTERN_ID": "907",
            "SPEED_VALUES": "10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10,10"
        },
```

I keep going around in circles with the HERE documentation which takes me to the same place every time
https://developer.here.com/documentation/route-matching/dev_guide/topics/here-map-content.html

This only highlights the first part of getting the TRAFFIC_PATTERN and not how to determine the PATTERN_ID lookup.

Can someone responsible for the new HERE documentation or has had it better explained please tell me how this is going to be done when s.fleet.ls.hereapi.com is deprecated?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use HERE Map Attributes API v8. This is replacing HERE Fleet Telematics API to get the map content.

For example you can use follow URL: https://**pde.api.here.com**/1/static.json?apiKey=F1UqxQFs8A7-zSUS7Hs8E5zT-pntHaH2CsQaVmtZ85s&content=TRAFFIC_PATTERN to do the lookup for pattern_id

Regards.